# Edge length wrong with scaling option

Tags: edges, scale

Why is the edge length not changed when I scale the object?

As in the picture below, the description of the edge length is not changed from 2m after scaling.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Changes you make in Object Mode aren't taken into account in Edit Mode.
You need first to Apply Scale in Object Mode with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> :

[image]

It will be reflected in Edit Mode:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the object scale with the mesh lengths. A mesh is contained by an object, which is like an invisible box, its own lengths don't depend on the object scale and vice versa.

The mesh can be 2x2x2 units large, if you keep the object scale at 1/1/1 the mesh will appear 2x2x2. If you scale the object in *Object* mode 2,743 times on the Z axis, the mesh will remain 2X2X2 even though it will appear 2x2x5,486 on the scene.

If you want the mesh lengths to be affected by the object scale you need to apply the scales (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>), the mesh will be 2x2x5,486 and the object will be back to 1/1/1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!